# uploaded image not displaying in ruby on rails app (everything else other than avatar are saving and updating )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am using paperclip for image uploading. the thing is, when the user login with fb, it is displaying the profile picture from fb, once he is logged in, he can change the profile picture in the app. but the changed picture is not displaying.
and i have default picture stored, that is displaying for the users registered with email. How can display new uploaded photo.

My user model is,

```
   has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb 

=> "100x100#" }
   validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.fullname = auth.info.name
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.skip_confirmation! unless user.confirmed?
      end
  end
```

My application helper is

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def avatar_url(user)
        if user.image
            user.image
        else
            "/images/missing.png"
        end
    end
end
```

My edit view

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-4" for="avatar">Profile picture</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    </div>
</div>
```

My show view is,

```
<%= image_tag avatar_url(@user), class: "avatar-full" %>
```

The SQL Transation is:

```
(0.0ms) begin transaction SQL (0.0ms)
UPDATE "sessions"
SET "data" = ?, "updated_at" = ? 
WHERE "sessions"."id" = ? [["data", "BAh7CEkiGXdhcmRlbi51c2VyLnVzZXIua2V5BjoGRVRbB1sGaSBJIiIkMmEk\nMTAkaWd6Nno3enNzU‌​jdja2F5ZzJWUXlXZQY7AFRJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7\nAEZJIjFpZnV2S0NTckczVDlhQmNEL0pIdnkw‌​TTY0Rk9LaXdXTzIwdXd6eVBl\nQ0lFPQY7AEZJIgpmbGFzaAY7AFR7B0kiDGRpc2NhcmQGOwBUWwZJIgt‌​ub3Rp\nY2UGOwBGSSIMZmxhc2hlcwY7AFR7BkAQSSIwWW91ciBhY2NvdW50IGhhcyBi\nZWVuIHVwZGF0‌​ZWQgc3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5LgY7AFQ=\n"], 
["updated_at", "2016-05-18 15:39:41.667689"], ["id", 57]]
(96.6ms) commit transaction
```

Comment: I am going to take a shot in the dark and say that your image is not saving.  Can you try adding a ! after your update method in the controller and post the output?  What is the return of user.image in the console?  what is the return of the avatar_url(user) in the console?

Comment: (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "sessions" SET "data" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "sessions"."id" = ?  [["data", "BAh7CEkiGXdhcmRlbi51c2VyLnVzZXIua2V5BjoGRVRbB1sGaSBJIiIkMmEk\nMTAkaWd6Nno3enNzUjdja2F5ZzJWUXlXZQY7AFRJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7\nAEZJIjFpZnV2S0NTckczVDlhQmNEL0pIdnkwTTY0Rk9LaXdXTzIwdXd6eVBl\nQ0lFPQY7AEZJIgpmbGFzaAY7AFR7B0kiDGRpc2NhcmQGOwBUWwZJIgtub3Rp\nY2UGOwBGSSIMZmxhc2hlcwY7AFR7BkAQSSIwWW91ciBhY2NvdW50IGhhcyBi\nZWVuIHVwZGF0ZWQgc3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5LgY7AFQ=\n"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-18 15:39:41.667689"], ["id", 57]]
   (96.6ms)  commit transaction

Comment: Is that the update action?

Comment: everything else other than avatar are saving and displying just the avatar is not updating

Comment: please show your migration file. when you add image to your table.

Comment: @MSK you can click the `edit` button directly below your question (above these comments) to add new details requested, such as the logs data, the migration file, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your field used for PaperClip upload

**Case 1**

If you have `t.attachment :image` as a field_name in your `Migration` then,

In your helper module

please change `user.image` to `user.image.url` or `user.image.url(:thumb)`

```
 module ApplicationHelper
    def avatar_url(user)
       if user.image.present?
          user.image.url #for original image
          #user.image.url(:thumb) #for thumbnail
      else
         "/images/missing.png"
      end
  end
end
```

In your Model

```
 has_attached_file :image
```

**Case 2**

And If you have `t.attachment :avatar` as a field_name in your `Migration` then,,

In your helper module

please change `user.image` to `user.avatar.url` or `user.avatar.url(:thumb)`

```
 module ApplicationHelper
    def avatar_url(user)
       if user.avatar.present?
          user.avatar.url #for original image
          #user.avatar.url(:thumb) #for thumbnail
      else
         "/images/missing.png"
      end
  end
end
```

and in your Model

in your method for Ominauth

```
user.avatar = auth.info.image
```